# Xamarin.Forms: ListView items are not displaying properly on Android Platform

Tags: listview, xamarin, xamarin.android, xamarin.forms, uwp

Good Day everyone. I'm creating a simple Xamarin.Forms (Portable) application that allows me to create record of an Employee and display it to a ListView.

I was able to do it on the UWP platform and make it appear like this:

[image]

But when I'm trying to run it on Android Platform. It doesn't display any value instead I only have empty page like this one:

[image]

---

What do you think is the reason behind this? These are my codes for this page:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<ContentPage xmlns="http://xamarin.com/schemas/2014/forms"
         xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2009/xaml"
         x:Class="XamarinFormsDemo.Views.ClientListPage"
         xmlns:ViewModels="clr-namespace:XamarinFormsDemo.ViewModels;assembly=XamarinFormsDemo"
         xmlns:controls="clr-namespace:ImageCircle.Forms.Plugin.Abstractions;assembly=ImageCircle.Forms.Plugin.Abstractions"
         BackgroundImage="bg3.jpg"
         Title="Customer List">


 <ContentPage.BindingContext>
    <ViewModels:CustomerVM/>
  </ContentPage.BindingContext>

  <StackLayout Orientation="Vertical">

 <ListView ItemsSource="{Binding CustomerList}"
          HasUnevenRows="True">
  <ListView.ItemTemplate>
    <DataTemplate>
      <ViewCell>
        <Grid Padding="10" RowSpacing="10" ColumnSpacing="5">
          <Grid.RowDefinitions>
            <RowDefinition Height="Auto"/>
            <RowDefinition Height="*"/>
          </Grid.RowDefinitions>
          <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
            <ColumnDefinition Width="Auto"/>
            <ColumnDefinition Width="*"/>
          </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>

          <controls:CircleImage Source="icon.png"
                 HeightRequest="66"
                 HorizontalOptions="CenterAndExpand"
                 Aspect="AspectFill"
                 WidthRequest="66"
                 Grid.RowSpan="2"
               />


          <Label Grid.Column="1"
                 Text="{Binding CUSTOMER_NAME}"
                 TextColor="#24e97d"
                 FontSize="24"/>



          <Label Grid.Column="1"
                  Grid.Row="1"
                   Text="{Binding CUSTOMER_CODE}"
                   TextColor="White"
                   FontSize="18"
                   Opacity="0.6"/>


          <Label Grid.Column="1"
              Grid.Row="2"
              Text="{Binding CUSTOMER_CONTACT}"
               TextColor="White"
               FontSize="18"
               Opacity="0.6"/>



        </Grid>
      </ViewCell>
    </DataTemplate>
  </ListView.ItemTemplate>

</ListView>


<StackLayout Orientation="Vertical"
         Padding="30,10,30,10"
         HeightRequest="20"
         BackgroundColor="#24e97d"
         VerticalOptions="Center"
         Opacity="0.5">
  <Label Text="© Copyright 2016   SMESOFT.COM.PH   All Rights Reserved "
         HorizontalTextAlignment="Center"
         VerticalOptions="Center"
         HorizontalOptions="Center" />
    </StackLayout>
  </StackLayout>

</ContentPage>
```

If you want to see more code, just please let me know. Thanks a lot.

Comment: You row definition only has 2 rows, but you are using 3 rows. Rows are 0 indexed. Other than that I don't see any issues with your ViewCell layout

Comment: @Cheesebaron If that's the case, why does the ListView displayed properly on UWP?

Comment: @Cheesebaron that seems to be very particular on a ListView in Android?

Comment: @JayceeEvangelista did you solve the above problem. I have the same problem.

Comment: I'm also facing same issue :(